# Results of volume calculation differ between cut/fill vs polygon volume in ArcGIS for Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.3, 3d-analyst, volume

I am using ArcGIS 10.3 for Desktop.

We just have a project that require to create a pond. So I get to the field to collect survey points for topography and work expense purpose (we use volume of the land that had been removed to calculate the expense). I want to know the volume of land that were taken out so I created TINs and convert them to Raster (one is for the land before removed and another one is the raster of the land after it have been finished) and run cut/fill then the result give me about 57000 cubic metres but when I run Polygon volume (3d analyst) it gave me up to 82000 cubic metres for the same survey points and TIN interface. I used to use Polygon volume to calculate volume of reservoir of water but never experience with cut/fill but one of my friends told me that cut/fill method is more accurate with earthwork. As the results are not even near and I don't know the process of each function very well. I can't tell which one is the correct one. I am confused now.

Please help explain me with details.

Comment: Polygon Volume intersects a surface with a polygon feature class. How do you get this polygon? From what you describe you have 2 surfaces as input.

Comment: The polygon is the top shape of the pond. I collected survey point to get the shape of the pond (top) using total station. And I drew it into ArcGIS and I am sure that the polygon is 100% intersects with the TIN surface below. In short I use two methods. The first one is that I collected the data of the land before it's removed and I went to collect it again after it is finished (this one use for cut/fill). The second one I only need data from my last survey to generate the TIN and intersect it with the top of the pond (polygon).

Comment: What is the cell size of your raster that you created from the TIN?

Comment: Observation 500

Comment: Please use the [edit] button beneath your question to revise it with these additional details.  Potential answerers do not always read comment trails.  I suspect that they may also need you to provide precise details (tools and parameter values) used in the two workflows that you used to perform your calculations.